# AVG official download site

Tags: windows-8.1, avg-antivirus

I want to download AVG internet security. I went to avg.com and clicked on the download button. Then my browser asks me if I want to **download or run the file from bits.avcdn.net**
I was expecting the download should also start from avg.com
Am I redirected to some mirror?

Comment: CDN means Content Distribution Network, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

General guidance…

Go to Google etc
type "who is avcdn.net"

Look who it is registered to. In this case Avast Software s.r.o.

*From comments:* It should be noted that Avast is the current owner of AVG.

In this particular case, `avcdn` is an abbreviation for Avast Content Distribution Network. Many companies use CDN structures.

These are some of the well-known ones, for future reference…

Cloudflare   [Stack Exchange uses this]
Akamai [Apple uses this one]
CloudFront [Also known as Amazon AWS]
Fastly
Level 3
Google Cloud CDN

There are many others, including local Telco systems
See [Wikipedia - Content delivery network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network)

Comment: You probably should add that [Avast is the owner of AVG](https://press.avast.com/avast-announces-agreement-to-acquire-avg-for-13b)

Comment: @DavidPostill - indeed. Will add. I've got so used to that being "known" that it simply didn't occur to me ;)

Comment: Barbara - it's not an official **website** of anyone. It's not a web site, it's a content delivery network. I'd be interested to see what the rest of their answer said, because that on its own is very misleading.

Comment: Just got an answer from avast: „we‘d like to inform you that the URL (bits.avcdn.net) you‘ve provided is not an official website of AVG. If you  wish to download AVG internet security, please use this link (clicking on the link leads me again to  avcdn.net ... so funny)

Comment: hahaha - That smacks of customer support reading from a card… & having not a clue what they're doing. It happens ;) Anyway, avcdn is **safe** for your download.